# how to add 24 hour to a specific date-time in bash

Tags: bash, datetime

I am trying to add 24 hours to a date-time string using bash, but the result is weird.

**That is okay:**

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "2016-01-01 21:00:00"
2016-01-01 21:00:00
```

Then trying to increase the date a little bit, but the result is completely wrong:

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "2016-01-01 21:00:00 + 1 day"
2016-01-02 20:00:00  <- expected: 2016-01-02 21:00:00

$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "2016-01-01 21:00:00 + 24 hours"
2015-12-31 22:00:00  <- expected: 2016-01-02 21:00:00

$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "2016-01-01 21:00:00 + 5 mins"
2016-01-01 16:01:00  <- expected: 2016-01-01 21:05:00
```

What is wrong with my command?

**--- UPDATE ---**

This is my current timezone settings:

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2022-12-26 23:58:14 WET
           Universal time: Mon 2022-12-26 23:58:14 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2022-12-26 23:58:14
                Time zone: Atlantic/Canary (WET, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no


$ cat /etc/timezone
Atlantic/Canary
```

---

**--- SOLUTION ---**

Thanks for your help I was able to figure out the correct command.

Solution 1:
adding time zone info `"Z"` to the end of my date-time string solved the problem

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "2016-01-01 21:00:00Z + 24 hours"
```

Solution 2:
Convert the date-time string to epoch, then add 24 hours to the value. Finally convert the new epoch back to string

```
date -d "@$(($(date "+%s") + 60 * 60 * 24))" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Which `date` are you using? BSD `date -d` does this:`-d dst   Set the kernel's value for daylight saving time.`

Comment: Why would the bash version matter? `date` isn't a bash built-in, it's a separate program.